# I need a jQuery function to only work above 700px screen size, cant spot the error in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, media-queries

I have a jquery function that i want to disable below 700px. I have the following function:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize();
     });
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if( $(this).width() > 700 ) {
        $(window).load(function() {
        $('.dh-container').directionalHover();
        });
        }
   });
</script>
```

This seems like it should work, but i'm a noob to jquery, and can't find the error in my code, and the chrome inspector isn't displaying any errors.

If someone could spot my error, that would be great. And in the future, how would i go about diagnosing a jquery error that the chrome inspector doesn't point out?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).resize();
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if( $(this).width() > 700 ) {
            $(window).load(function() {
                alert("It's Working above 700px width");
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Always start by testing simple procedures to find out mistakes.

Another way:

```
<script> 
var width = $(window).width();
        if (width > 700) {
            alert('Display Above 700px');
        } else {
            alert('Do nothing since it's under 701px');
        }
</script>
```